# Can the port parameter be 80 or 443 in socket_bind() function?

Tags: javascript, php, html, websocket

I am not sure if I am asking a correct question. But please help me with this issue.

I am implementing real-time chatting application with PHP and websocket. I am behind a firewall which allows only 80 and 443, so I plan to use only those two ports. I tried two ways:

### First,

I think the web page should be downloaded using port 80, but websocket must use another port, i.e. 443.

`...
    $port = 443;
    socket_bind($socket, $host, $port);
    ...`

However, I got error message as below.

`PHP Warning:  socket_bind(): unable to bind address [13]: Permission denied in /home/cabox/workspace/a/b/c/server/class.PHPWebSocket.php on line 121`

This implies that websocket can't use 443, doesn't it?

### Second,

According to [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-bind.php), I removed `$port` parameter, then the php file runs without error.

Does it imply that both of HTTP server and socket server are using port 80?

But in client-side, I see error `WebSocket connection to 'ws://xxx.com/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200`.

Is there any way to do so?

I expect kind help.

Comment: You can host the websocket server under another path, e.g. `ws://xxx.com/socket`, not sure how that can be done with your library. Also note that `443` is rhe standard port for https / tls so if you offer that from your server that port is blocked.

Comment: @JonasW. I changed the server url into `0.0.0.0/socket`, but I see error message `PHP Warning:  socket_bind(): Host lookup failed [-10001]: Unknown host`.

Comment: @Miron ports <1024 are so-called privileged, and guess what : you dont have enough privileges to bind to one. Take this to the sysadmin if it is 'really' a requirement. Second, you should not use a privileged port for this, but rather have the firewall opened for a well known port that you can later bind to.

Answer (score 1):

The $port parameter is optional only because it is not used by the AF_UNIX protocol. But if, as I guess, you use the AF_INET protocol (see your socket_create() options), you will have to specify the port to use in the binding of your socket.

Ports 80 and 443 are used for HTTP and HTTPS. I'm afraid that if you don't want to override them, you will have to open another port in your firewall.